# Simple digit counter method in Java

Tags: java, methods, counter

I am trying to create a method that will count the number of occurrences of digits in a string and record them into an array.

For example if the string entered into the method is "1223000", then counter[1] =1, counter[2] =2, counter[3] = 1, counter[0] = 3.

I keep getting a arrayindexoutofbounds  error, here is the code I have soo far:

```
//method: count number of occurences for digits
    public static int[] count(String s){

        int[] counter = new int[10];

        for(int j= 0; j < s.length(); j++){
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(j)))
                counter[s.charAt(j)] += 1;
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: You need to map from the digit character to the number; subtract '0'. e.g. counter[s.charAt(j) - '0']++;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875967/simple-digit-counter-method-in-java#comment15801384_11875967) for how to correct the issue.

You should also consider looping the characters of the string directly, rather than tracking the position in the string and using `charAt`.

For example,

```
public static int[] countDigits(final String str) {
  final int[] freq = new int[10];
  for (final char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      ++freq[c - '0'];
    }
  }
  return freq;
}
```

Testing the above using the below code results in no error (`java -ea DigitFreqTest`).

```
final String input = "1223000";
final int[] freq = countDigits(input);
assert freq[0] == 3 && freq[1] == 1 && freq[2] == 2 && freq[3] == 1;
```

---

Note the above does not support Unicode... in that case, you may wish to instead use [`Character.getNumericValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)).

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countNumerals(final String str) {
  final Map<Integer, Integer> freq = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(10);
  for (final char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      final int num = Character.getNumericValue(c);
      Integer occ = freq.get(num);
      if (occ == null) {
        occ = 0;
      }
      freq.put(num, occ + 1);
    }
  }
  return freq;      
}
```

Note I had to improvise using a `Map<Integer, Integer>` because Java does not inherently provide a multiset collection :-(

Comment: Is that your final answer? :)

Comment: @MattGreer I know it's not Unicode friendly (since `Character.isDigit` is not limited to ASCII), but it'll do here ;)

Comment: Awesome thanks..I guess I should have done more research on the .charAt() method. I assumed that the method was returning the actual integer value for digits.

Answer (score 4):

s.charAt(j) will give you the character number for that number, not it's integer value.

It's terribly corrected code, but you'll get the right idea:
`String s = "1223000";
        int[] counter = new int[10];`

```
    for(int j= 0; j < s.length(); j++){

        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(j))) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(j, j+1));
            counter[i] += 1;
        }
            //unter[s.charAt(j)] += 1;
    }</code>
```

Comment: `counter` only needs to be `int[10]`, since decimal numbers only have ten digits ;) +1 for contributing, however.

Comment: Yup, processed that afterwards :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `s.charAt(j)` in `counter[s.charAt(j)]` will return number as `char` for example `'1'` and then convert char to int using ASCII so `char '1'` will be `int 49` so out of array index.

Comment: Ya it makes total sense now. Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the counter array (int[] counter) should be the length of s:
int[] counter = new int[s.length()];

Comment: He is counting digits in base ten, so he only needs 10 buckets

Answer (score 0):

If you guys want a counter for anything, just turn it into a string, then use the string method .length() to figure out the length, if that's what you're looking for. And if I'm not mistaken, the length() method returns an integer, so there you go. And as shown somewhere on this page, arrays have the same attribute, but that's for how many spaces there are that have things stored in them.